# How to interpret time zone 2013-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00?

Tags: python, timezone

What does +02:00 mean ?

My sqlalchemy + pandas translate it into

```
2013-03-31 22:00:00
```

Is that correct ?

Comment: It's the time zone; two hours ahead of UTC (GMT), so somewhere in eastern Europe, or Africa.

Comment: It is an iso8601 time string, utc +2 hours, +2 is not a timezone it is an offset.

Comment: Midnight on April Fools' Day 2013 in UTC+2 was 10 pm on 31st March in the UTC (GMT) time zone, so the change by SQLAlchemy and Pandas is 'correct' for the new time zone of `Z` or `+00:00`.

Comment: Probably not correct for Germany.  I would expect Germany to be on UTC+1 during the winter and UTC+2 during the summer (checking at http://worldtimezone.com/ to be sure).  At the end of March or beginning of April, I believe that Europe has switched to summer (daylight saving) time.  Therefore, the original time could be midnight in Germany.  The modified time would still be correct in UTC (Z or Zulu time), but not correct in the UK (it would be on UTC+1 at the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2013-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00` is not a time zone -- it is a time specified in [rfc 3339 format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6).

> What does +02:00 mean ?

It means that the utc offset is +2 hours where utc offset is defined as:

```
<local time> = <utc time> + <utc offset>
```

Note: utc offset is also not a time zone:

```
- multiple timezones may have the same utc offset at some point
- the same timezone may have different utc offset at different times
```

> my sqlalchemy + pandas translate it into `2013-03-31 22:00:00` Is that correct ?

`2013-03-31 22:00:00` is the corresponding utc time. It is correct if the system expects time in UTC here.

Answer (score 1):

The time string `2013-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00` is an [ISO 8601:2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) notation for the instant of midnight (to the nearest millisecond) on April Fools' Day (1st April) 2013 in a time zone with offset UTC+2 (two hours ahead or east of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

In the string the `+02:00` is the time zone offset from UTC.  Midnight on April Fools' Day 2013 in UTC+2 was 10 pm on 31st March in the UTC (GMT) time zone, so the change by [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is 'correct' for the new time zone offset for UTC, aka `Z` or ['Zulu time'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones) or +00:00.

Germany uses a time zone offset of UTC+1 during the winter and UTC+2 during the summer (checking at [worldtimezone.com](http://worldtimezone.com/) to be sure). By the end of March or beginning of April, Europe has switched to summer (daylight saving) time. The [rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe) used in Europe is 'summer time starts on the last Sunday in March and ends on the last Sunday in October'. Therefore, the original time could be midnight in Germany. The modified time would still be correct in UTC or GMT, but not the correct local time in the UK (the UK would be on British Summer Time, BST, or UTC+1 at the time).